# Why use getAttribute and setAttribute?

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to better understand the fundamentals of A-Frame.

I understand how to use the getAttribute() and setAttribute() methods for 
accessing component data.  However I don't understand **why** we use them instead of just accessing the components attributes using dot notation.

A lot of people use something like:
document.querySelector("#myText").getAttribute('text').value

Why not use:
document.querySelector("#myText").components['text'].data.value

Is there something wrong with using that second way?  What are the pitfalls?  In my experiments I have experienced both ways returning "undefined" due to the code running before the scene is finished loading, but I have learned how to avoid that using the "loaded" event.

As you can see at this glitch example (https://glitch.com/~text-hierarchy) I've successfully printed data to the console using both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part of the standard**

Both `getAttribute(prop)` and `setAttribute(prop, value)` are used to get/set attributes of any other DOM elements. MDN links here ([get](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute), [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute))

**Compatible with aframe components**

If you have a [update()](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#handling-property-updates) function in your a-frame component, setAttribute() calls it, notyfing, that a property of a component has changed.

---

It's not mandatory, it's even faster to modify some properties directly, but it has risks, like undefined behavior if a developer uses `update()` to monitor changes.

Comment: Thank you so much.